Can LlamaParse return as a pydantic object?
I have been unable to make LlamaParse return the parsed content in a strictly structured format,like Pydantic objects. Otherwise I would have to make a separate api call just to make it the parsed content structured.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
